# System.exit(0) doesn't work appropriately when working with Realm

Tags: azure

> to IntroExample and I see the same(eventually getting ANR and dialog
>   with closing app), btw I'm using Android 5.1, Android 4.2.2.  With
>   closing Activity with finish() as mentioned in that link or
>   killProcess(myPid()) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your object isalive or not